# Highchar display wrong month in date chart

Tags: javascript, date, highcharts

The Following Chart suppose to show the September month but instead its showing the October, what's wrong here. in the date series its clearly showing the month 9 which is September but its showing October. ? Thanks in Advance.

```
 <script>
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
},

    title: {
text: 'Wahab Jaan Chart'
},
yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Profi / Loss'
        },
        tickInterval: 5
    },
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
},
series: [{
    data: [


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 13), 1110],


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 29), 1100.02],


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 29), 4110.02],

                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 29), 8304.02],

                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30), 8314.36],


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30), 8324.64],


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30), 8334.66],


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30), 8324.38],


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30), 8334.3],


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30), 8344.18],


                [Date.UTC(2016, 09, 30), 7334.18],




     ]

}]
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript Date, month 0 is Jannuary, 1 is February, etc...
So month 9 is indeed October.

Comment: oh ok, but my date is coming from database which has the exact date how i can extract one month from it ?

Comment: when you convert it from what you get in your database, just subtract 1 from the month.